# Difficulty with predict () function from a logit model in R

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
   admit gre  gpa rank
1      0 380 3.61    3
2      1 660 3.67    3
3      1 800 4.00    1
4      1 640 3.19    4
5      0 520 2.93    4
6      1 760 3.00    2
7      1 560 2.98    1
8      0 400 3.08    2
9      1 540 3.39    3
10     0 700 3.92    2
11     0 800 4.00    4
12     0 440 3.22    1
13     1 760 4.00    1
14     0 700 3.08    2
15     1 700 4.00    1
16     0 480 3.44    3
17     0 780 3.87    4
18     0 360 2.56    3
19     0 800 3.75    2
20     1 540 3.81    1
21     0 500 3.17    3
22     1 660 3.63    2
23     0 600 2.82    4
24     0 680 3.19    4
25     1 760 3.35    2
```

I have run the following code:

```
library(aod)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)
binary<-read_csv("binary.csv")
head(binary)
binary<-na.omit(binary)
summary(binary)
sapply(binary, sd)
xtabs(~admit + rank, data = binary)
binary$rank <- factor(binary$rank)
mylogit <- glm(admit ~ gre + gpa + rank, data = binary, family = "binomial")
summary(mylogit)
confint(mylogit)
confint.default(mylogit)
wald.test(b = coef(mylogit), Sigma = vcov(mylogit), Terms = 4:6)
exp(cbind(OR = coef(mylogit), confint(mylogit)))
newbinary1 <- with(binary, data.frame(gre = mean(gre), gpa = mean(gpa), 
                                      rank = factor(1:4)))
newbinary1$rankP <- predict(mylogit, newbinary = newbinary1, type = "response")
newbinary1
```

And receive this error: "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, rankP, value = c(`1` = 0.172626540888155,  : 
  replacement has 400 rows, data has 4"

Does R think that my data is a tibble? Is that the problem? Everything appears to work until the newbinary1$rankP line. Thank you for any help

Comment: The `predict` function does not have an argument named `newbinary=`. The argument name is `newdata=`. The command `predict(mylogit, newbinary1, type = "response")` will probably do what you want.

Comment: Even if it was tibble, it wouldn't have thrown an error. Tibble and dataframe are used almost interchangeably nowadays. The error is because there is a mismatch between the number of rows on LHS and RHS. It's most likely that newbinary1 has four rows whereas your predict function returned 400 rows. Also as dcarlson pointed out, the argument name is incorrect, it should have been newdata instead of newbinary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @dcarlson, you need to specify `newdata` in your `predict` call.

```
newbinary1$rankP <- predict(mylogit, newdata = newbinary1, type = "response")
newbinary1
#    gre    gpa rank      rankP
#1 620.8 3.4264    1 0.93469298
#2 620.8 3.4264    2 0.13957803
#3 620.8 3.4264    3 0.74519103
#4 620.8 3.4264    4 0.05425203
```

Always read the documentation.

```
?predict
```

**Description**

> predict is a generic function for predictions from the results of
>   various model fitting functions. The function invokes particular
>   methods which depend on the *class* of the first argument.

```
class(mylogit)
#[1] "glm" "lm"

?predict.glm
```

Comment: You guys are the best. Thank you so much. Problem solved.